# Recursive Scala Case class Reduction

Tags: recursion, scala

I have a case class that is recursive and looks like this:

```
case class Config(name: String, isEnabled: Boolean, elems: Map[String, MyCase])

case class MyCase(
  id: String,
  isActive: Boolean,
  elems: Option[Map[String, MyCase]])
```

Where the `Config` contains the `id` of the `MyCase` entries contained as a `Map`. I have to iterate over this structure and come up with a `Map` that contains the parent child relations. Say for example., if I have the `Config` class represented as below (for simplicity, I have just given the `id`'s):

```
Config(Map("5" -> myCase1, "6" -> myCase2))

5 - Config
 1
  1
  2 
 2
6
 1
```

where `id`'s 5 and 6 are top level entries which in turn has a recursive structure. I have to now come up with a `Map` that contains the parent child relationship for the `id`'s. So for the case above, I will expect a `Map` that looks like:

```
Map(
 "5" -> Seq("5.1"),
 "5.1" -> Seq("5.1.1", "5.1.2"),
 "5.1.1" -> Seq.empty[String],
 "5.1.2" -> Seq.empty[String],
 "6" -> Seq("6.1"),
 "6.1" -> Seq.empty[String]
)
```

Notice how I append the parent `id` to the child.

Given a `Seq` of such `Config`s,

```
val configs = Seq(Config1, Config2)
```

this is what I have come up with:

```
def relationsFor(config: Config): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {

    def prepareChildren(parentId: String, acc: Map[String, Seq[String]], subElems: Map[String, MyCase]): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
      subElems.collect {
        case (id, elem) if elem.isActive =>
          val newAcc = acc ++ Map(parentId -> subElems.keys.map(subElemId => s"$parentId.$subElemId").toSeq)
          if (elem.elems.isDefined) {
            val newParentId = s"$parentId.$id"
            val newAcc1 = newAcc ++ Map(s"$parentId.$id" -> elem.elems.get.keys.map(subElemId => s"$newParentId.$subElemId").toSeq)
            prepareChildren(s"$parentId.$id", newAcc1, elem.elems.get)
          } else {
            acc ++ Map(s"$parentId.$id" -> Seq.empty[String])
          }
      }
    }.flatten.toMap

    configs.collect {
      case config if config.isEnabled =>
        config.elems.collect {
          case (parentId, elemCase) if elemCase.elems.isDefined =>
            prepareChildren(parentId, Map.empty[String, Seq[String]], elemCase.elems.get)
          case (parentId, _) =>
            Map(parentId -> Seq.empty[String])
        }
    }.flatten.flatten.toMap
  }
```

Could this be simplified ? I have already tested this and it works as expected, but I find it a little bit hard to understand. Can this be made much more elegant? I mean can the `relationsFor` method be made more elegant ?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried do it a different way, when you asked this question on StackOverflow.. You find my version below, first I'll try to give you some feedback on your version :

- I see you regularly use `isDefined` together with pattern matching or if / else. I would replace this by matching for `Some` / `None` or even better with a combination of `map` and `getOrElse` or with `fold` :

  ```
  o.map(f).getOrElse(b)
  o.fold(b)(f)
  ```

  These are more ideomatic ways to handle an `Option` and unwrap the `Option` for you where you want to use it (calling `get` on an `Option` is something you should try to minimize).
- It seems like you could have reused `newParentId` in the places where you wrote `s"$parentId.$id"`, this would mean that `newParentId` should be placed outside the if else.
- I am not sure if you can change the signature of `MyCase`, but I am not sure what extra the `Option` brings for `elems`, but this may be moot if you want to differentiate between `None` and `Map.empty[String, MyCase]]`, if you don't then no collection or an empty collections is pretty much the same.

---

Here's what I came up with :

```
def getMapWithChildIds(config: Config): Map[String, Seq[String]] = {
  def mkId(prefix: String, key: String): String = 
    if (prefix.isEmpty) key else prefix + "." + key

  def go(map: Map[String, MyCase], prefix: String): Map[String, Seq[String]] =
    map.flatMap { case (key, elem) => 
      val fullKey = mkId(prefix, key)
      // this will handle an unactive MyCase the same way as a MyCase with no elems
      Option(elem).filter(_.isActive).flatMap(_.elems).fold(
        Map(fullKey -> Seq.empty[String]))(
        submap => {
          val directSubKeys = submap.keys.map(mkId(fullKey, _)).toList
          // map entry for this key + entries for sub keys
          Map(fullKey -> directSubKeys) ++ go(submap, fullKey)
        })
    }

  go(config.elems, "")
}
```

Which gives for :

```
val noMap: Option[Map[String, MyCase]] = None

val config =
  Config("a", true,
    Map(
      "5" -> MyCase("id?5", true, 
        Some(Map(
          "1" -> MyCase("id?5.1", true,
            Some(Map(
              "1" -> MyCase("id?5.1.1", true, noMap),
              "2" -> MyCase("id?5.1.2", true, noMap)
            ))
          ),
          "2" -> MyCase("id?5.2", true, noMap)
        ))
      ),
      "6" -> MyCase("id?6", true, 
        Some(Map(
          "1" -> MyCase("id?6.1", true, noMap)
        ))
      )
    )
  )
```

The following result :

```
val map = getMapWithChildIds(config)
// Map[String,Seq[String]] = Map(5.2 -> List(), 5.1.2 -> List(), 5 -> List(5.1, 5.2), 5.1.1 -> List(), 6 -> List(6.1), 6.1 -> List(), 5.1 -> List(5.1.1, 5.1.2))

map.toList.sortBy(_._1).foreach(println)
// (5,List(5.1, 5.2))
// (5.1,List(5.1.1, 5.1.2))
// (5.1.1,List())
// (5.1.2,List())
// (5.2,List())
// (6,List(6.1))
// (6.1,List())
```

Comment: You are awesome! Your other example for my other question was a lot readable. Let me see if I can further simplify my version without those if else and isDefined on the Option!

Comment: The reason why I need the extra Option for the elems is that I'm reading this case class from JSON and there might or might not be this nesting for some elements

Comment: Have a look at my EDIT. I tried to come up with a simpler version, but just not sure if it would work. I could not test it right now. Will do it perhaps later. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much better version, but it does not give me exactly what I want:

```
case class Config(name: String, isEnabled: Boolean, elems: Map[String, MyCase])

case class MyCase(
  id: String,
  isActive: Boolean,
  elems: Option[Map[String, MyCase]])

def prepareChilds(parentId: String, acc: Seq[(String, Seq[String])], elems: Seq[(String, MyCase)]): Seq[(String, Seq[String])] = {
  elems.foldLeft(acc) {(newAcc, elem) =>
    val (assetId, assetConfig) = elem
    if (assetConfig.elems.isDefined) {
      prepareChilds(
        s"$parentId.$assetId",
        newAcc :+ (parentId, assetConfig.elems.get.filter(_._2.isActive).keys.toSeq),
        assetConfig.elems.get.filter(_._2.isActive).toSeq)
    } else {
      newAcc :+ (parentId, Seq.empty[String])
    }
  }
}

val noMap: Option[Map[String, MyCase]] = None
val config =
  Config("a", true,
    Map(
      "5" -> MyCase("5", true, 
        Some(Map(
          "1" -> MyCase("5.1", true,
            Some(Map(
              "1" -> MyCase("5.1.1", true, noMap),
              "2" -> MyCase("5.1.2", true, noMap)
            ))
          ),
          "2" -> MyCase("5.2", true, noMap)
        ))
      ),
      "6" -> MyCase("6", true, 
        Some(Map(
          "1" -> MyCase("6.1", true, noMap)
        ))
      )
    )
  )
```

For the following input:

```
val result = prepareChilds("5", Seq.empty[(String, Seq[String])], config.elems.toSeq)
```

I get the following result:

```
List((5,ArrayBuffer(1, 2)), 
    (5.5,ArrayBuffer(1, 2)), 
    (5.5.1,List()), 
    (5.5.1,List()), 
    (5.5,List()), 
    (5,ArrayBuffer(1)), 
    (5.6,List())
)
```